# cs0030:Unable to generate a temporary class

Tags: c#

I have a Web Service, when I try to generate the object of it I am getting below error.

> "Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'ShortSell.ShortSellRQOriginDestinationInformationFlightSegment[]' to 'ShortSell.ShortSellRQOriginDestinationInformationFlightSegment'error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'ShortSell.ShortSellRSOriginDestinationOptionFlightSegment[]' to 'ShortSell.ShortSellRSOriginDestinationOptionFlightSegment'error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'ShortSell.ShortSellRQOriginDestinationInformationFlightSegment[]' to 'ShortSell.ShortSellRQOriginDestinationInformationFlightSegment'error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ShortSell.ShortSellRQOriginDestinationInformationFlightSegment' to 'ShortSell.ShortSellRQOriginDestinationInformationFlightSegment[]'error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ShortSell.ShortSellRSOriginDestinationOptionFlightSegment' to 'ShortSell.ShortSellRSOriginDestinationOptionFlightSegment[]'error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ShortSell.ShortSellRSOriginDestinationOptionFlightSegment' to 'ShortSell.ShortSellRSOriginDestinationOptionFlightSegment[]'"}

I tried changing the temp folder properties to writable but I am still getting this error.  Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: The following thread seems to cover this exact problem. Maybe the solutions posted there also apply to your case? http://forums.asp.net/t/1469891.aspx/1

Comment: Yes, Heinzi it seems same but any suggetions what should i do as i am not able to find any solution of it???

Comment: What about the part that reads "*the solution for this one is to run over the wsdl mapping file and change all from [][] ---> []*"?

Comment: I tried the Same but Still Getting the Same Error..

Answer (score 24):

It's a known bug that won't be fixed:

- Microsoft Connect: [XmlSerializer Code Generation component cannot handle nested unbounded elements when there is only one element](https://web.archive.org/web/20120621134819/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/471297)

The error occurs when a complex type in the wsdl contains exactly one element with unbounded occurrence. The workaround, taken from [this forum discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/e33305c3-b5f6-4922-8a3f-df202088d25a) (credit to Elena Kharitidi), is to add dummy attributes to such types:

```
<xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:element ../>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="tmp" type="xs:string" />      <-- add this
```

and

```
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="tmp" type="xs:string" />      <-- add this
```

Comment: Spent hours looking for this GREAT answer

Comment: Microsoft is serious about not fixing their bugs. The bug still exists. Thank you for the GREAT answer

Comment: It's ridiculous that nearly 3 years later this is still required.  Ah well - thank you :)

Comment: Not 3 years, but 5: the bug has been opened in 2009. It's really amazing. Aren't there any other workaround ? Maybe a custom serializer ?

Comment: Just banged my head against this error and yes, it still exists.  Thanks for this!

Comment: I'll keep up the tradition to give an update on this issue. Anno 2016 this issue is still there and this answer still provides a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my wdsl there was no "xs:sequence" element, so I couldn't apply wsdl file change directly. However, I fixed the issue by referencing below post.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27507816/503446